# spring render welcome file like a text

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I am new in spring, my issue is that index.jsp show me like text.
this is my web.xml
I use netbeans, spring 4, glassfish and maven

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

spring-servlet.xml

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd 
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.2.xsd
">
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
    <context:annotation-config />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/images/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/bootstrap/**" location="/resources/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/js/" />    
    <context:component-scan base-package="mx.com.shopping.cart.spring.controller" />
    <bean id="jspViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"></property>
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

[my tree directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCjLR.png)
but show
[browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUdiI.png)

Comment: Don't map `*.jsp` to the `DispatcherServlet` let the container handle those.

Comment: i replace *.jsp for / but when i run show 404 error in root, i have to put /project/index.jsp for show the welcome file(index.jsp). if i put *.htm show  my welcome file but my request in controller doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Let your spring dispatcher map your urls. So in your web.xml change your welcome-file to:

```
<welcome-file>/</welcome-file>
```

then in your controller add a mapping for index.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String viewIndex() {
   return "index";
}
```

And put your index.jsp inside your WEB-INF/jsp folder